# CRUD op Express.js Node.js Mysql Cannot insert using MVC

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Im trying to impl CRUD operations using React.js, Express.js and Node so I write a basic code and thats working but I wanna use Model and Controller to have a clean code so thats not working and send me error I don't know what the problem is so can someone here guide me to make it works please. by the way the Get works but for insert no.

I test it with postman and I get:

> ```
> Error : Cannot POST /api/insert
> ```

Here is the code :

**Controller.js**

```js
// create new car   
exports.createNewCar = (req, res) =>{
    const carReqData = new CarModel(request.body);
    console.log('carReqData', carReqData);
    // check null
    if(req.body === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0){
        res.send(400).send({success: false, message: 'Please fill all fields'});
    }else{
        CarModel.createCar(carReqData, (err, car)=>{
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.json({status: true, message: 'Car Created Successfully', data: car.insertId})
        })
    }
}
```

**Model.js**

```js
// create new car
var Car = function(car){
    this.idCars = car.idCars;
    this.carName = car.carName;
    this.carModel = car.carModel;
}
Car.createCar = (carReqData, result) =>{
    db.query('INSERT INTO Cars SET ?', carReqData, (err, res)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('Error while inserting data');
            result(null, err);
        }else{
            console.log('Car created successfully');
            result(null, res)
        }
    })
}
```

**Routes.js**

```js
// create new car
router.post('/insert', carController.createNewCar);
```

**Index.js**

```js
app.use('/insert', CarRoutes);
```

Comment: Your POST route error is returning a prefix of '/api', so check your router definition, see here for how to prefix routes, might give you something to look for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68910733/crud-op-express-js-node-js-mysql-cannot-insert-using-model-and-controller#68910733

Comment: @ConBran Yeah I should add /api to route of post... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the issue by editing the route

**Routes.js**

```
router.post('/', carController.createNewCar);
```

**index.js**

```
app.use('/app/insert', CarRoutes);
```